Sending/receiving messages and sending files via Bluetooth application Android Studio (java)
I am currently working on creating a Bluetooth application in Android Studio. The main functionalities I aim to implement are sending/receiving messages and transferring files between paired devices. As I am new to this, my code might seem a bit unconventional to some of you.
I managed to pair with other devices. But when the devices are connected and I try to send a message, I simply do not get any notification on the external paired device.
Here are the relevant parts of the code responsible for the functionalities I mentioned earlier:

public class MainActivity2 extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final String TAG_MAIN_ACTIVITY_2 = "Main_Activity2";
    private static final int REQUEST_ENABLE_BT = 1;
    private static final int SELECT_FILE = 3;
    Button mPairedBtn;
    private ListView listMainChat;
    private EditText edCreateMessage;
    private Button btnSendMessage;
    private Button btnSendFiles;
    private Button btnChooseFiles;
    ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> startForFileResult; //launcher to launch file selection action
    private ArrayAdapter<String> adapterMainChat;
    private ArrayList<String> messagesList;
    private static final int LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST = 101;
    private static final int SELECT_DEVICE = 102;
    private static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1;
    private Context context;
    BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter;
    private ChatUtils chatUtils;
    public static final int MESSAGE_STATE_CHANGED = 0;
    public static final int MESSAGE_READ = 1;
    public static final int MESSAGE_WRITE = 2;
    public static final int MESSAGE_DEVICE_NAME = 3;
    public static final int MESSAGE_TOAST = 4;
    public static final String DEVICE_NAME = "deviceName";
    public static final String TOAST = "toast";
    private String connectedDevice;
    //managing the appropriate transfer of messages
    private Handler handler = new Handler(new Handler.Callback() {
        @Override
        public boolean handleMessage(@NonNull Message msg) {
            switch(msg.what){
                case MESSAGE_STATE_CHANGED:
                    switch(msg.arg1){
                        case ChatUtils.STATE_NONE:
                            setState("Not connected");
                            break;
                        case ChatUtils.STATE_LISTEN:
                            setState("Listening...");
                            break;
                        case ChatUtils.STATE_CONNECTING:
                            setState("Connecting...");
                            break;
                        case ChatUtils.STATE_CONNECTED:
                            setState("Connected: " + connectedDevice);
                            sendNotification("Connected to " + connectedDevice);
                            break;
                    }
                    break;
                case MESSAGE_WRITE:
                    byte[] buffer1 = (byte[]) msg.obj;
                    String outputBuffer = new String(buffer1);
                    adapterMainChat.add("Me: " + outputBuffer);
                    sendNotification("Me: " + outputBuffer);
                    break;
                case MESSAGE_READ:
                    byte[] buffer = (byte[]) msg.obj;
                    String inputBuffer = new String(buffer, 0, msg.arg1);
                    adapterMainChat.add(connectedDevice + ": " + inputBuffer);
                    messagesList.add(connectedDevice + ": " + inputBuffer);
                    sendNotification(connectedDevice + ": " + inputBuffer);
                    adapterMainChat.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    break;
                case MESSAGE_DEVICE_NAME:
                    connectedDevice = msg.getData().getString(DEVICE_NAME);
                    Toast.makeText(context,connectedDevice,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case MESSAGE_TOAST:
                    Toast.makeText(context,msg.getData().getString(TOAST),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
    private void setState(CharSequence subTitle){
        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        if(actionBar != null){
            actionBar.setSubtitle(subTitle);
        }
    }
    ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> startForDeviceSelecting;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        EdgeToEdge.enable(this);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

        ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(findViewById(R.id.main_getting_dev), (v, insets) -> {
            Insets systemBars = insets.getInsets(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.systemBars());
            v.setPadding(systemBars.left, systemBars.top, systemBars.right, systemBars.bottom);
            return insets;
        });
        mPairedBtn = findViewById(R.id.PairedDEVI);
        mPairedBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                otworzOknoUrzadzen(DeviceListActivity.class);
            }
        });
        startForDeviceSelecting = registerForActivityResult(new ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(), new ActivityResultCallback<ActivityResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onActivityResult(ActivityResult o) {
                if(o != null && o.getResultCode() == SELECT_DEVICE){
                    if(o.getData() != null){
                        showToast("Selecting device to chat");
                        Log.d(TAG_MAIN_ACTIVITY_2,"Selecting device to chat");
                    }else{
                        showToast("Did not select any device to chat");
                        Log.d(TAG_MAIN_ACTIVITY_2,"Did not select any device to chat");
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        startForFileResult = registerForActivityResult(new ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(), new ActivityResultCallback<ActivityResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onActivityResult(ActivityResult result) {
                if(result.getResultCode() == RESULT_OK && result.getData() != null){
                    Uri uri = result.getData().getData();
                    if( uri != null){
                        showToast("Sending a choosen file " + result.getData());
                        Log.d(TAG_MAIN_ACTIVITY_2,"Sending a choosen file ");
                        sendFile(uri);
                    }else{
                        showToast("Cannot send choosen file " + result.getData());
                        Log.d(TAG_MAIN_ACTIVITY_2,"Cannot send choosen file ");
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        btnSendFiles = findViewById(R.id.btn_send_files);
        btnSendFiles.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity2.this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    // If the permissions are not granted, demand them
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity2.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
                    Log.d(TAG_MAIN_ACTIVITY_2,"Permissions granted");
                }
                else{
                    Intent intent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
                    startForFileResult.launch(intent);
                    Log.d(TAG_MAIN_ACTIVITY_2,"Sending file");
                }

            }
        });
        btnChooseFiles = findViewById(id.btn_choose_file);
        btnChooseFiles.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity2.this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    // If the permissions are not granted, demand them
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity2.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
                    Log.d(TAG_MAIN_ACTIVITY_2,"Permissions granted");
                }else{
                    openFilePicker();
                    showToast("You've opened the files compound ");
                    Log.d(TAG_MAIN_ACTIVITY_2,"You've opened the files compound  ");
                }

            }
        });

        // Receive data passed from DeviceListActivity
        String deviceAddress = getIntent().getStringExtra("device_address");
        if (deviceAddress != null) {
            // Establish a connection with a Bluetooth device
            connectToDevice(deviceAddress);
        } else {
            showToast("No device address received");
            Log.e(TAG_MAIN_ACTIVITY_2,"No device address received");
        }

        context = this;
        init();
        initBluetooth();
        chatUtils = new ChatUtils(context,handler);
        messagesList = new ArrayList<>();
        adapterMainChat = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, messagesList);
        listMainChat.setAdapter(adapterMainChat);
    }

    private void connectToDevice(String deviceAddress) {
        if (bluetoothAdapter == null) {
            showToast("Bluetooth adapter is not available");
            return;
        }
        BluetoothDevice device = bluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice(deviceAddress);
        chatUtils.connect(device);
    }

    private void openFilePicker() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        intent.setType("*/*");
        startForFileResult.launch(intent);
        showToast(" Files compound ");
        Log.d(TAG_MAIN_ACTIVITY_2," Files compound ");
    }
    private void init(){
        listMainChat = findViewById(R.id.list_conversation);
        edCreateMessage = findViewById(R.id.ed_enter_message);
        btnSendMessage = findViewById(R.id.btn_send);
        listMainChat.setAdapter(adapterMainChat);
        adapterMainChat = new ArrayAdapter<String>(context,R.layout.message_layout);

        btnSendMessage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String message = edCreateMessage.getText().toString();
                if (!message.isEmpty()) {
                    messagesList.add("Me: " + message);
                    adapterMainChat.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    edCreateMessage.setText(" ");
                    chatUtils.write(message.getBytes());
                    sendNotification("Message sent: " + message);
                    sendMessage(message);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private void sendMessage(String message) {
//        Log.d(TAG_MAIN_ACTIVITY_2, "Trying to send message: " + message);
//        if (chatUtils.getState() != ChatUtils.STATE_CONNECTED) {
//            showToast("You are not connected to a device");
//            Log.e(TAG_MAIN_ACTIVITY_2,"You are not connected to a device");
//            return;
//        }
        // Convert message to bytes and send
        if (message.length() > 0){
            byte[] send = message.getBytes();
            chatUtils.write(send);
            sendNotification("Message sent: " + message);
        }
    }
    private void initBluetooth(){
        bluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        if(bluetoothAdapter == null){
            showToast(" No Bluetooth found ");
            Log.d(TAG_MAIN_ACTIVITY_2," No Bluetooth found ");
        }
    }
    private void checkPermissions(){
        if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity2.this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            //no guaranteed permits, so we have to give them:
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity2.this,new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST);
        }else{
            showToast("Starting to get paired devices");
            Log.d(TAG_MAIN_ACTIVITY_2,"Starting to get paired devices");
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity2.this,DeviceListActivity.class);
            //startActivity(intent);
            startForDeviceSelecting.launch(intent);
        }
    }
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        if(requestCode == SELECT_DEVICE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null){
            //RESULT_OK ---> resultCode
            String address = data.getStringExtra("device Address");
            showToast("Address: " + address);
            Log.d(TAG_MAIN_ACTIVITY_2,"Address: " + address);
            chatUtils.connect(bluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice(address));
        }

        else if(requestCode == REQUEST_ENABLE_BT && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data !=null){
            Uri uri = data.getData();
            if(uri != null){
                openFile(uri);
                showToast(" Files compound activate ");
                Log.d(TAG_MAIN_ACTIVITY_2," Files compound activate ");
            }
        }
        if (requestCode == SELECT_FILE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null) {
            Uri selectedFileUri = data.getData();
            sendFile(selectedFileUri); // Send chosen file via BT
            showToast(" Choosing file to be sent ");
            Log.d(TAG_MAIN_ACTIVITY_2," Choosing file to be sent ");
        }
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }

    // Method to sending file via Bluetooth
    private void sendFile(Uri fileUri) {
//        if (chatUtils.getState() != ChatUtils.STATE_CONNECTED) {
//            showToast("You are not connected to a device");
//            Log.d(TAG_MAIN_ACTIVITY_2,"You are not connected to a device");
//            return;
//        }else{
//            sendNotification("Connected to a device");
//        }

        // Convert Uri's file into byte board
        byte[] fileBytes = readFileBytes(fileUri);

        //Check if the file had been sent properly
        if (fileBytes == null) {
            showToast("Error reading file");
            Log.d(TAG_MAIN_ACTIVITY_2,"Error reading file");
            return;
        }
        // Send file via bluetooth
        chatUtils.write(fileBytes);
        showToast("File sent successfully");
        Log.d(TAG_MAIN_ACTIVITY_2,"File sent successfully");
    }

    // Method to loading file content into byte board
    private byte[] readFileBytes(Uri fileUri) {
        try {
            InputStream inputStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(fileUri);
            ByteArrayOutputStream byteBuffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

            int bufferSize = 1024;
            byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

            int len;
            while ((len = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                byteBuffer.write(buffer, 0, len);
            }

            return byteBuffer.toByteArray();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG_MAIN_ACTIVITY_2, "Error reading file", e);
            return null;
        }
    }

    private void openFile(Uri uri){
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setDataAndType(uri, getContentResolver().getType(uri));
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
        private void otworzOknoUrzadzen(Class obj){
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity2.this,obj);
//        startActivity(intent);
            startForDeviceSelecting.launch(intent);
    }
    private void showToast(String msg){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),msg,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        if(requestCode == LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST){
            if(grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                //if permissions have been granted - create new executive window
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity2.this,DeviceListActivity.class);
                //startActivity(intent);
                startForDeviceSelecting.launch(intent);

            }else{
                new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity2.this)
                        .setCancelable(false)
                        .setMessage("Location permission is required. \n Please allow.")
                        .setPositiveButton("Grant", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                checkPermissions();
                            }
                        })
                        .setNegativeButton("Deny", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                MainActivity2.this.finish();
                            }
                        }).show();
            }
        }else{
            super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        }
    }
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if(chatUtils != null){
            chatUtils.stop();
            Log.d(TAG_MAIN_ACTIVITY_2, "ChatUtils stopped");
        }
    }
    private void sendNotification(String message) {
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        String channelId = "BluetoothChatChannel";
        String channelName = "Bluetooth Chat Notifications";
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(channelId, channelName, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
        }
        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, channelId)
                .setSmallIcon(drawable.scan_icon1)
                .setContentTitle("Bluetooth Chat")
                .setContentText(message)
                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH);
        notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, notificationBuilder.build());
    }
}
public class ChatUtils {
    private final Handler handler;
    private Context context;
    private ConnectThread connectThread;
    private AcceptThread acceptThread;
    private static final UUID APP_UUID = UUID.fromString("acb67583-fb51-4cce-afc7-8512b3487313");
    private static final String APP_NAME = "BluetoothChatAppSection";
    private static final String TAG_CHAT_UTILS = "CHAT_UTILS";
    BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter;
    private ConnectedThread connectedThread;
    public static final int STATE_NONE = 0;
    public static final int STATE_LISTEN = 1;
    public static final int STATE_CONNECTING = 2;
    public static final int STATE_CONNECTED = 3;
    private int state;

    public ChatUtils(Context context, Handler handler) {
        this.context = context;
        this.handler = handler;

        state = STATE_NONE;
        bluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
    }

    public int getState() {
        return state;
    }

    public synchronized void setState(int state) {
        this.state = state;
        handler.obtainMessage(MainActivity2.MESSAGE_STATE_CHANGED, state, -1).sendToTarget();
    }

    public synchronized void start() {
        if (connectThread != null) {
            connectThread.cancel();
            connectThread = null;
        }
        if (acceptThread == null) {
            acceptThread = new AcceptThread();
            acceptThread.start();
        }
        if (connectedThread != null) {
            connectedThread.cancel();
            connectedThread = null;
        }
        setState(STATE_LISTEN);
    }

    public synchronized void stop() {
        if (connectThread != null) {
            connectThread.cancel();
            connectThread = null;
        }
        if (acceptThread != null) {
            acceptThread.cancel();
            acceptThread = null;
        }
        if (connectedThread != null) {
            connectedThread.cancel();
            connectedThread = null;
        }
        setState(STATE_NONE);
    }

    public void connect(BluetoothDevice device) {
        if (state == STATE_CONNECTING) {
            if (connectThread != null) {
                connectThread.cancel();
                connectThread = null;
            }
        }
        connectThread = new ConnectThread(device);
        connectThread.start();

        if (connectedThread != null) {
            connectedThread.cancel();
            connectedThread = null;
        }

        setState(STATE_CONNECTING);
    }

    public void write(byte[] buffer) {
        ConnectedThread connThread;
        synchronized (this) {
            if (state != STATE_CONNECTED) {
                return;
            }
            connThread = connectedThread;
        }
        connThread.write(buffer);
    }

    private class AcceptThread extends Thread {
        private final BluetoothServerSocket serverSocket;

        @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
        public AcceptThread() {
            BluetoothServerSocket tmp = null;
            try {
                tmp = bluetoothAdapter.listenUsingRfcommWithServiceRecord(APP_NAME, APP_UUID);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG_CHAT_UTILS, "Accept->Constructor", e);
            }
            serverSocket = tmp;
        }

        public void run() {
            BluetoothSocket socket = null;
            try {
                socket = serverSocket.accept();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG_CHAT_UTILS, "Accept->Run", e);
                try {
                    serverSocket.close();
                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    Log.e(TAG_CHAT_UTILS, "Accept->Close", e1);
                }
            }
            if (socket != null) {
                synchronized (ChatUtils.this) {
                    switch (state) {
                        case STATE_LISTEN:
                        case STATE_CONNECTING:
                            connected(socket, socket.getRemoteDevice());
                            break;
                        case STATE_NONE:
                        case STATE_CONNECTED:
                            try {
                                socket.close();
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                Log.e(TAG_CHAT_UTILS, "Accept->CloseSocket", e);
                            }
                            break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        public void cancel() {
            try {
                serverSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG_CHAT_UTILS, "Accept->CloseServer", e);
            }
        }
    }

    private class ConnectThread extends Thread {
        private final BluetoothSocket socket;
        private final BluetoothDevice device;

        @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
        public ConnectThread(BluetoothDevice device) {
            this.device = device;
            BluetoothSocket tmp = null;
            try {
                tmp = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(APP_UUID);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG_CHAT_UTILS, "Connect->Constructor", e);
            }
            socket = tmp;
        }

        @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
        public void run() {
            try {
                socket.connect();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG_CHAT_UTILS, "Connect->Run", e);
                try {
                    socket.close();
                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    Log.e(TAG_CHAT_UTILS, "Connect->CloseSocket", e1);
                }
                connectionFailed();
                return;
            }
            synchronized (ChatUtils.this) {
                connectThread = null;
            }
            connected(socket, device);
        }

        public void cancel() {
            try {
                socket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG_CHAT_UTILS, "Connect->Cancel", e);
            }
        }
    }

    private class ConnectedThread extends Thread {
        private final BluetoothSocket socket;
        private final InputStream inputStream;
        private final OutputStream outputStream;

        public ConnectedThread(BluetoothSocket socket) {
            this.socket = socket;
            InputStream tmpIn = null;
            OutputStream tmpOut = null;
            try {
                tmpIn = socket.getInputStream();
                tmpOut = socket.getOutputStream();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG_CHAT_UTILS, "ConnectedThread", e);
            }
            inputStream = tmpIn;
            outputStream = tmpOut;
        }

        public void run() {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int bytes;
            while (true) {
                try {
                    bytes = inputStream.read(buffer);
                    handler.obtainMessage(MainActivity2.MESSAGE_READ, bytes, -1, buffer).sendToTarget();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG_CHAT_UTILS, "Input stream was disconnected", e);
                    connectionLost();
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        public void write(byte[] buffer) {
            try {
                outputStream.write(buffer);
                handler.obtainMessage(MainActivity2.MESSAGE_WRITE, -1, -1, buffer).sendToTarget();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG_CHAT_UTILS, "Error during write", e);
            }
        }

        public void cancel() {
            try {
                socket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG_CHAT_UTILS, "ConnectedThread->Cancel", e);
            }
        }
    }

    private void connectionLost() {
        Message message = handler.obtainMessage(MainActivity2.MESSAGE_TOAST);
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString(MainActivity2.TOAST, "Connection Lost");
        message.setData(bundle);
        handler.sendMessage(message);
        ChatUtils.this.start();
    }

    private synchronized void connectionFailed() {
        Message message = handler.obtainMessage(MainActivity2.MESSAGE_TOAST);
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString(MainActivity2.TOAST, "Can't connect to the device");
        message.setData(bundle);
        handler.sendMessage(message);
        ChatUtils.this.start();
    }

    @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
    private synchronized void connected(BluetoothSocket socket, BluetoothDevice device) {
        if (connectThread != null) {
            connectThread.cancel();
            connectThread = null;
        }
        if (connectedThread != null) {
            connectedThread.cancel();
            connectedThread = null;
        }
        if (acceptThread != null) {
            acceptThread.cancel();
            acceptThread = null;
        }
        connectedThread = new ConnectedThread(socket);
        connectedThread.start();

        Message message = handler.obtainMessage(MainActivity2.MESSAGE_DEVICE_NAME);
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString(MainActivity2.DEVICE_NAME, device.getName());
        message.setData(bundle);
        handler.sendMessage(message);
        setState(STATE_CONNECTED);
    }
}

enter image description here
enter image description here
enter image description here

Where do you expect a message to appear on the remote device? Are you running an app to receive the messages?

Thank You very much Michael Kotzjan for Your rapid question, I really appreciate that.
I was thinking about, that sent message would apper as a notification in paired smartphone for e.x.
But maybe from Your experience You think that it would be better to shwo it in TextView ?
I run app not only to recive but also to send messages and files via bluetooth.
I can show You some of demo screens of my app

@MichaelKotzjan yesterday I edited my post and You can see ,,interface". That ListView is a place where my sending text is shown. Maybe You got some solution for those issues ?

Are your images showing the sending or the receiving device? It is still not clear to me how you want the messages to appear as notofications on the receiving device. Does the receiving device run an app to receive messages and convert them to notifications?

@MichaelKotzjan i just try to send a message to paired device, and I want this message to appear as a notification on other device or maybe better solution for that would be if message appears on the ListView.
For now the only thing I got is that showed on another picture. I recive notification on my phone, while writing and sending a message. But I want this notification to be shown also on the paired device e.x. smartphone.

BLE does not offer anything that lets you display a notification on the receiving end. You would need to write a second app (or reuse the existing one) to receive the message via BLE and display a notification for you

Thank You very much @MichaelKotzjan
And may I ask You, do You know how to send files via Bluetooth ? (parts of my code that are intended for this activity are also in previous message).
Till now I was able to open my files compound, where I can choose which file I want to send. But I cannot send them via bluetooth to paired device e.x. smartphone (I do not see any activity of sending on paired device).

In the past, files have been sent using Bluetooth Classic (also called Bluetooth Serial). Android phones still support this and using it would result in the receiving device to display a dialog where you can accept the file. But BLE functions entirely different and you will always need a receiving app on the other device. BLE also has a limited message length, you most likely need to split your file and reconstruct it on the receiving end. But a file can be sent like every other message using BLE, nothing special about it.
